# Google Maps gets weird when i'm open infoWindow's (UTF-8)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using Google maps for a new project, but my map gets weird when I open an `infoWindow`.

See the picture below:

[image: image description]

Does anyone recognize this problem?

**Here is my code for the map initialization:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.398554, 5.486206);
        var mapOptions = {
            draggable: true, 
            zoomControl: true, 
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID]
            }, // here´s the array of controls
            disableDefaultUI: true, // a way to quickly hide all controls
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 13,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">FjørSilkeBris</h2>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p>Førland, 5570 Aksdal</p>'+
            '<p>481 49 246 (Mobil)</p>'+
            '<p>Facebook: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/FjorSilkeBris">FjørSilkeBris på facebook.</a></p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title:"Fjørsilkebris"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        initialize();
    }
});
```

Comment: define "gets weird"...
Is your problem that you do not expect the grey box in the screenshot to appear?

Comment: @HaemEternal No, i have marked the wierd parts with red rings.. 

It gets a square shadow outside the infowindow and "wave"-shaped lines inside the infowindow..

Comment: It is probably the css, not the code.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks! Solved my problem. It was the css framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem.

The problem is, some CSS on your page is most likely setting the `img` element's `max-width` property to 100%. This breaks the infowindow's css on the map.

What you can do is override the img max-width of your map's canvas div example:

```
#divMap img { max-width: none; }
```

This worked for me

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Rather than just pointing out the problem, it actually offers a solution